# JavaScript, Array and functions - only last element of array works

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and been learning. I'm trying to set a button to activate random functions. button is fine and if I assign getGroupOne() to a button or getGroupTwo() to a button it works fine.

The only problem is somewhere in the following code.

Well when I click my button only getGroupTwo() works with the following code,

```
function getGroup() {
    var Group = new Array (getGroupOne(), getGroupTwo());
    var whichOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*Group.length); 
        return Group[whichOne];};
```

But when I flip them ... only getGroupOne() works with the following code,

```
function getGroup() {
    var Group = new Array (getGroupTwo(), getGroupOne());
    var whichOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*Group.length); 
        return Group[whichOne];};
```

Could someone let me know what is the problem, I looked at a couple answers but not completly sure how to fix this.

Thank you,

Comment: Could it be that you want to have an array of functions instead of an array of whatever these functions return? That would be `var Group = [getGroupTwo, getGroupOne];`. But you don't show what you are doing with the return value of `getGroup`, so it's hard to tell. In any case, if you want a random number from a range including the upper bound, you have to add one: `Math.floor(Math.random()*(Group.length + 1))`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random.

Comment: @FelixKling is probably right. You want to have `var Group = [getGroupTwo, getGroupOne];'`, then you'll call `getGroup()()`. First `()` invokes `getGroup` to receive one of the two functions, the other `()` invokes that received function.

Comment: *edit:* Scratch the last part of my comment, I was somewhere else with my thoughts.

Comment: What does `getGroupOne()` and `getGroupTwo()` return? Do you want to join two arrays into `var Group` or do you want an array with length 2?

Comment: been playing with +1 doesn't appear to be working yet ... but will read up and play with it. I don't think it is an array, but I'm a beginner so I have functions inside of functions everywhere and trying to condense them into two groups and run them with one button.

Comment: Your random formula is right. What happened to the answers?

Comment: @Jeff We need to know what is inside of `getGroupOne` and `getGroupTwo`.  Specifically, we need to know what the functions return.  When you set up your array `[getGroupOne, getGroupTwo]`, if you call them like you are `[getGroupOne(),getGroupTwo()]` you're actually firing *BOTH* sets of functions, right then and there, before you even calculate your random number.  So the array is full of whatever is returned from those functions (maybe `undefined`?), and your randomizer is returning what the function returned.  If you mean to return a function, itself, then don't use the `()`, just the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return function references, you should write it like this:

```
function getGroup() 
{
    var Group = [getGroupOne, getGroupTwo],
    whichOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * Group.length);

    return Group[whichOne];
}

getGroup()();
```

Comment: Ahh, that totally works was banging my head against the wall with all the other comments. thank you very much ... owe you one.